# Quelle est la différence entre égarer et perdre?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes

Ces deux mots me semblent avoir le même sens (*to lose*). Comment sait-on quand utiliser égarer et quand utiliser perdre?

Par exemple:

> J'ai perdu mes clés.

vs

> J'ai égaré mes clés.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Perdre* est un verbe plus fort et définitif tandis qu'*égarer* signifie que l'on pourrait les retrouver.

Si on perd ses clés, il n'y a pas de chance de les récupérer (c'est définitivement perdu).

Si on égare ses clés, on pourrait les retrouver (elles sont peut-être dans la maison ou au bureau).

Comment: Le caractère définitif n'est vrai que quand *perdre* est employé au sens figuré: *elle a perdu ses parents très jeune* ou *il a perdu sa virginité* (*égarer ses parents* et *égarer sa virginité* sont très improbables). On peut en revanche très bien retrouver des clefs qu'on a perdu.

Answer (score 2):

The difference you make in your answer is a subtlety that is not totally foreign to the compared meanings of those two words but not entirely exact. Before getting to that let's see about something else; one difference in the use of the two words is on the count of currency: "perdre" is the word used in the spoken language; the other one is used rather rarely that way and is found in writing but [less than "perdre"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perdre%2C%C3%A9garer&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperdre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9garer%3B%2Cc0). That shows that French people do not use the two words strictly according to the difference you perceive but that they often say "perdre" when they could have said "égarer"; the reason is that the meaning of "perdre" covers in great part that of "égarer".

1.

> The meaning of égarer:  Mettre (quelque chose) en un endroit qu'on oublie et où on ne peut (le) retrouver par la suite; perdre momentanément.

Your supposition concerning "égarer" is true as regards a greater chance of finding what has been lost because, as you say, you lost it in a well known and relatively small place 
(in an office, on the front yard lawn, etc.); that idea  contained in "perdre momentanément" corresponds to the use of the word only when you do find what you had lost. If you use the word according to this idea you say "J'avais égaré mes clés" (but now I've got them back), whereas in the other case (considered next) you say "J'ai égaré mes clés.) (You haven't found them yet, and possibly you never will).

The second possibility (Mettre (quelque chose) en un endroit qu'on oublie et où on ne peut (le) retrouver par la suite) shows that what has been lost might never be found again (for instance in the case of keys that fell into a dustbin in the office and were thus lost forever).

The points to stress in acknowledging a difference in the use of "égarer":

- the reason for loosing something is inattention while manipulating the object,
- you know  well the place and it is a small place that you can search,
- there is a fair chance of getting back what you lost.

In English the translation of "égarer" is normally "to mislay".

2. "Perdre" does not mean "lose forever" when it's used in the case of objects that are not in your possession any more because you dont know where they are; the two possibilities remain: you might find those objects if you're lucky enough or if you look for them with enough perseverance.

Answer (score 1):

La première différence est que le mot 'égarer' a un sens purement géographique, 'perdre' est plus général. On peut perdre un emploi, de l'argent, son temps ou ses parents, mais on ne les égare pas.

Answer (score 0):

Complément :

A/ Ce [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9garer%2Cperdre%2C%C3%A9gar%C3%A9%2Cperdu&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9garer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperdre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9gar%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperdu%3B%2Cc0) illustre probablement que le verbe *égarer* n'est pas courant.

B/ "Égarer" n'a pas tout à fait le même sens que "perdre". "Perdre" c'est : "égarer définitivement". "J'ai perdu ma montre cet été sur la plage". "Égarer" est moins fort, c'est "ne pas retrouver quelque chose" mais cette perte peut être momentanée.

Référence :  https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/%C3%A9garer.php

Comment: Le caractère définitif de *perdre* n'est pas systématique. *[...] ne vous fâchez pas si je laisse aujourd'hui épancher ma joie sur votre frère que j'avais perdu, et que j'ai retrouvé contre mon attente* Bossuet.

Comment: @jlliagre: Si on va par là, le caractère définitif de *définitif* n'est pas systématique non plus :)

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne comprends pas du tout ton commentaire.  "Perdre" c'est : "égarer définitivement". Ça c'est du dictionnaire Cordial. Est-ce erroné ?

Comment: Disons que c'est exagéré. Tout dépend de ce qu'on perd. TLFi: *Perdre: sens 1: Être privé provisoirement ou définitivement de.*

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Definitively true...